# jquery - Grab all the values from the form and put it in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Im trying to grab all the values from my form and then set the value of my textarea with the values I'm getting from the form .

heres my jquery

```
$('#formButton').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $inputs = $("#myForm fieldset input");
    $inputs.each(function() {
      a = $(this).val();
      $('#description').val(a);
      console.log(a)
    });
 });
```

I'm just grabbing my inputs and iterating through it when i console log the value I get a list of all my values from that input

however when i try to set the val to that variable into my description textarea The only value i see in there is the LAST ONE.

so if i input a b c

only c

gets put into my textarea.  I need the whole thing in there.

heres a link to my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CP943/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.map().get()`:

```
$('#formButton').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var a = $("#myForm :input").map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(''); // creates a comma separated string.
  $('#description').val(a); // set the values here.
});
```

---

In your code you were updating your values in each iteration so that was giving you the last value always.

Comment: Thanks for that...learned something new today.  Do you have any tips on formatting the output?  I want to be able to add labels and such to the output so that its easily readable

Answer (score 1):

The code block you write is logically works. But .each function make the loop for $('description') always new one.

```
$('#formButton').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $inputs = $("#myForm fieldset input");
    var allValues='';
    $inputs.each(function() {
        a = $(this).val();
        allValues+=a;
        console.log(a)
    });
      $('#description').val(allValues);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were writing to the `#description`, not appending.

```
$('#formButton').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = [];
  var $inputs = $("#myForm fieldset input");
    $inputs.each(function() {
        var a = $(this).val();
        data.push(a);
        console.log(a)
    });
   $('#description').val(data.join(' '));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CP943/8/